# CodeIgniter: Session data dissapears after refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Like I said in title. I have problem in CodeIgniter (version 3.1.6 and 3.1.7).
In same method - it's working, but went I call userdata in other method, or other controller, or model I see only this:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('user_session'));
```

> 

Let's look at simple example (remember, it's not my full code!):
So, controller Sessiontest.php:

```
class Sessiontest extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    //session library loaded by autoload.php
  }
  public function firstStep()
  {
    echo 'set userdata';
     $data = array(
      'example1' => '123',
      'example2' => 321
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_session', $data);
    print_r($this->session->userdata('user_session'));
  }
  public function secondStep()
  {
    echo 'get userdata ';
    print_r($this->session->userdata('user_session'));
  }
}
```

And in browser:
.../sessiontest/firststep:

> set userdataArray ( [example1] => 123 [example2] => 321 )

.../sessiontest/secondstep:

> get userdata

Same effect when I use files driver and database driver.
Any help will be appreciated. I don't hide that I'm beginner, but I can't resolve this without any kind of help.

//Edit #1:
Additional: 
Tested in Opera and in Chrome.

//Edit #2:
Every refresh creates next new session file when I'm using files driver, and next new row in database, when I'm using database driver.

//Edit #3:
Changes suggested in the answers.

Comment: Assign your session with a name and get with that name. eg:when assigning data to the session - `$this->session->set_userdata('namehere', $data);` and when getting session value `$this->session->userdata('namehere');`

Comment: Are you destroying session somewhere in your code? Are you sure you're on the last version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it now, second time.
@ankit-singh I put small edit, with same results.

Comment: Show us your session and cookie config settings.

Comment: then probably somewhere in your code your session is being destroy...

Comment: No way, how? Thank you! I've typo in cookies config. Thank you very much!  @DFriend

Comment: When everything else looks right and yet sessions don't work it's usually the config.

Comment: Have you set the session save path don't leave it NULL

Answer (score -1):

`$this->load->library('session');` //load seesion library

`$this->session->set_userdata('name',$data);` you have not give the name of session variable

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not change anything.
I loaded session library in autoload.php

Comment: I ran your code in my computer and ran successfully.@Micosh

Comment: It seems like my session is new everytime I refresh page, but why?

Comment: when you logout kill session or unset session